# Dropdown menu not dropping

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

Why is the reports dropdown menu not working. The one dropdown for `user.username` works just fine?

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a style="color: white;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    {{ user.username }}
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

                    <button class="btn dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                    <div class="btn-group ">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href=#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports</a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <button class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'option2020:export' %}">Template</button>
                                <button class="dropdown-item" href="#">Full Reports</button>
                            </div>

                    </div>  

                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {% else %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a `"` in Line 11 at `href=#"`, should be `href="#"`.

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports</a>
```